# Set Default Display Mode in Blender's File Browser?

Tags: file-browser

Whenever I'm using Blender's file browser, I prefer to see the files in the thumbnail display mode, instead of the vertical list. So I have to change it every time by clicking on the display mode button. is there a way to set the display mode to thumbnail on default?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It seems to remember whatever you set it to before exiting Blender here (3.0.1). You may need to have Auto-save Preferences on (which I do by default here) but I've not checked that.

Comment: Thanks! That fixed the problem.

Comment: Good! I'll carry on with your penguin tutorial now... :^)

Comment: @JohnEason: you made my day!!!!!!!! :D pls show us your ready made pinguin if your made it through the series!!!!

Comment: @Chris I'll think about it, but it depends how much of a mess I make of it and I certainly wouldn't upload it here! :^)

Comment: @JohnEason : now you made me sad…would love to see it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Open up Blender, and press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> to save the file.
- In the file browser, switch the display mode to thumbnail.
- Then hit the cancel button, to close the file browser.
- Then open Blender's *user preferences*, and hit the *save preferences*
  button.

Thanks to [John Eason](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/104232/john-eason) for helping me figure this out.

Comment: You can also do it by enabling Show Thumbnail in Preference>Save & Load>File Browser.